# I can ping my localhost but I can't with other IP address

Tags: java, udp, ping

I have here a UDP ping client. I don't know if I did it right but I think it works if I set `127.0.0.1` as the IP address. But it won't if I set it to, for instance, the IP address of Google. I get an exception:  `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out` .

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PingClient {

    private static final int AVERAGE_DELAY = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception    {
        int port = 4997;
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(port);

        for(int i=1;i<=10;i++) {
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024] ;
            Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
            String ping="PING "+ i +" "+cal.getTimeInMillis()+" ms"+"\r\n";
            buf=ping.getBytes("UTF-8");
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("69.63.176.11");
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, address, port);
            packet.setData(buf);
            socket.send(packet);
            Thread.sleep( 10* AVERAGE_DELAY);
            DatagramPacket server_response = new DatagramPacket(new byte[1024], 1024);
            socket.setSoTimeout(1000);
            socket.receive(server_response);
            printData(server_response);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't ping"? Exception? No answer? Also, as to 2., yes, since 127.0.0.1 is loopback, and is your own machine.

Comment: Is there anything on UDP port 4997 on the remote computer that you expect to get an answer from?

Comment: @fge: I get an exception: `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out`

@JoachimPileborg: No, there is not. I just invented it. Is that an issue? Sorry, I'm not yet familiar.

Comment: Also, a "ping" as sent by the command line `ping` command works completely different compared to your program. The standard ping uses [ICMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol) instead of UDP.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is your localhost. yes you can ping it without internet connection.

Comment: For your program to work, it needs a server program listening on the port you send the packets to. If it isn't then you will get errors.

Comment: Oh yeah! That completely slipped my mind. Thank you! I have a server. Please see edit Sir @JoachimPileborg :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ping is an interesting dinosaur of the internet era.

Unfortunately you didn't specify which platform you're on.  On Windows platforms, 127.0.0.1 (which is the localhost address) will not route through the actual network adapter.  Microsoft has optimized localhost routing to go through a different part of the stack so it will work all the time regardless of a network connection.

On Unix based hosts, you'll be able to see the packets using a network sniffer going to the 'lo' or loopback interface.  These will work regardless of an internet connection.

Ping, which is a VERY old protocol, uses the ICMP protocol.  I believe this is actually a layer down or possibly in the same networking layer as UDP but it is not a UDP message.

As another member commented on the question - if there is nothing listening on the port you're sending to then the client you're writing will fail.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) for more information on what the 'ping' command does.

**EDIT for more information**
I think I see the problem - there are two different port numbers in play client is creating socket on port 4997 and server is creating socket on port 8117.  This seems to be part of the mismatch.

I did a quick google search which may point you in the right direction. See [this article](http://systembash.com/content/a-simple-java-udp-server-and-udp-client/) for more information.

I haven't programmed TCP/UDP level stuff in many years so I apologize that I can't give more substantive information.